# Making a parser to extract function name, parameters, return type

Tags: c++, parsing

I need to parse a C++ class file (.h) and extract the following informations:

1. Function names
2. Return types
3. List of parameter types of each function

Assume that there is a special tag using which I can recognize if I need to parse a function or not.

For eg.

```
#include <someHeader>  

class Test
{
    public:
    Test();

    void fun1();
    // *Expose* //
    void fun2();  

};
```

So I need to parse only fun2().

I read the basic grammar [here](http://homepages.e3.net.nz/~djm/cppgrammar.html#decl-specifier-seq), but found it too complex to comprehend.

Q1. I can't make out how complex this task is. Can someone provide a *simpler* grammar for a function declaration to perform this parsing?

Q2. Is my approach right or should I consider using some library rather than reinventing?

---

Edit: Just to clarify, I don't have problem parsing, problem is more of understanding the grammar I need to parse.

Comment: But why are you trying to parse a C++ header ?

Comment: If you don't have to do that (for homework, for example) don't reimplement but use a library/another tool to do that. C++ is ridiculously hard to parse.

Comment: [This question maybe helps you](http://stackoverflow.com/q/526797/237483)

Comment: @NeelBasu I will be given a header file with some of the functions tagged as 'to be exposed'. I need to make Adaptor and Proxy classes for the same, which will require me to know the exact function name, parameters etc.

Answer (score 1):

A C++ header may include arbitrary C++ code. Hence, parsing the header might be as hard as parsing all kinds of C++ code.

Your task becomes easier, if you can make certain assumptions about your header file. For instance, if you always have an EXPOSE-tag in front of your function and the functions are always on a single line, you could first grep for those lines:

```
grep -A1 EXPOSE <files>
```

And then you could apply a regular expression to filter out the information you need.

Nevertheless, I'd recommend using existing tools. [This seems to be a tutorial](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/07/03/parsing-c-in-python-with-clang/) on how to do it with clang and Python.

Comment: That is exactly how I am doing it. I dont have a problem in parsing it using C++ itself, problem is that I am finding the grammar itself difficult to understand, and thus to actually think about the logic required to parse.

Answer (score 0):

[GCC XML](http://www.gccxml.org/HTML/Index.html) is an open source tool that emits the AST (Abstract Syntax Tree). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9231426/874024) other answer where I posted about the usage I made of it.

You should consider to use only if you are proficient (or akin to learn) with an XML analyzer for inspecting the AST. It's a fairly complex structure...

You will need anyway to 'grep' for the comments identifying your required snippets, as comments are lost in output XML.

Answer (score 0):

IF you are doing this just for documentation [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) could be a good bet.

Either way it may give you some pointers as to how to do this.